# WordPress SQL syntax error, works fine in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Here is my full SQL query (variable named $query) that I'm echo'ing out right before the actual query:

```
UPDATE wp_portfolio_items SET caption='This is a caption',item_order=1,image='20130705104136Layer-651.jpg' WHERE id=1; UPDATE wp_portfolio_items SET caption='This is another caption',item_order=2,image='20130705104137photo.JPG' WHERE id=2;
```

If I copy that query and run it in phpMyAdmin's SQL tab, it runs fine and updates the two rows. However, when this is queried in WordPress it gives this WordPress error:

**WordPress database error:** [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE wp_portfolio_items SET caption='This is another caption',item_order=2,ima' at line 1]
`UPDATE wp_portfolio_items SET caption='This is a caption',item_order=1,image='20130705104136Layer-651.jpg' WHERE id=1; UPDATE wp_portfolio_items SET caption='This is another caption',item_order=2,image='20130705104137photo.JPG' WHERE id=2;`

I doubt this is necessary to include, but I'll do it anyways. This is the code where I run the query:

```
    if ($query != "") {
        echo $query . "<br><br>";
        $wpdb->show_errors();
        $wpdb->query($query);
        exit;
    }
```

Any ideas why WordPress would have a problem with this query, but phpMyAdmin can run it just fine?

Comment: Can you please show us $query variable which you defined with that query?

Answer (score 2):

You can't run multiple queries in a single statement.

phpMyAdmin parses the SQL you enter so it handles multiple queries by extracting them and executing them one by one.

Comment: Ah. I tried it with a single query and it gave me the same error, so I figured it wasn't the multiple queries. However, I just realized I still had the semicolon at the end, and removing the semicolon fixed it. Thanks!